# many to one problem

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

i have this error for some hours now and i don't get it anymore. It's a project with Spring 2.5 and hibernate3. I have tried with declaring a project object in the client object too.

I have 2 tables: client and project

```
CREATE TABLE client (clientId INT NOT NULL,
                     PRIMARY KEY (clientId)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE TABLE project (projectId INT, clientId INT,
                    INDEX par_ind (clientId),
                    FOREIGN KEY (clientId) REFERENCES client(clientId)
                      ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

in Java code:

```
public class Project implements Serializable {

 private int id;
 private String name;
 private String description;
 private Date startDate;
 private Date endDate;
 private String manager;
 private Client client;

 public Project(String name, Date startDate, Date endDate) {

  this.name = name;
  this.startDate = startDate;
  this.endDate = endDate;
 }

 public int getId() {
  return id;
 }

 public void setId(int id) {
  this.id = id;
 }

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

 public String getDescription() {
  return description;
 }

 public void setDescription(String description) {
  this.description = description;
 }

 public Date getStartDate() {
  return startDate;
 }

 public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
  this.startDate = startDate;
 }

 public Date getEndDate() {
  return endDate;
 }

 public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
  this.endDate = endDate;
 }

 public String getManager() {
  return manager;
 }

 public void setManager(String manager) {
  this.manager = manager;
 }

 public Client getClient() {
  return client;
 }

 public void setClient(Client client) {
  this.client = client;
 }

 public String toString() {
  StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
  buffer.append("Project name: " + name);
  buffer.append("Project description: " + description);
  buffer.append("Project start date: " + startDate);
  buffer.append("Project end date: " + endDate);
  return buffer.toString();
 }

 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if ((obj instanceof Project)
    && (((Project) obj).getName() == this.name)) {
   return true;
  }
  return false;
 }

}



public class Client implements Serializable {

 /**
  * 
  */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private int id;
 private String name;
 private String company;
 private String location;
 private String city;
 private String country;

 public Client() {

 }

 public Client(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

 public int getId() {
  return id;
 }

 public void setId(int id) {
  this.id = id;
 }

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

 public String getCompany() {
  return company;
 }

 public void setCompany(String company) {
  this.company = company;
 }

 public String getLocation() {
  return location;
 }

 public void setLocation(String location) {
  this.location = location;
 }

 public String getCity() {
  return city;
 }

 public void setCity(String city) {
  this.city = city;
 }

 public String getCountry() {
  return country;
 }

 public void setCountry(String country) {
  this.country = country;
 }

 public String toString() {
  StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
  buffer.append("Client name: " + name);
  buffer.append("Client company: " + company);
  buffer.append("Client location: " + location);
  buffer.append("Client city: " + city);
  buffer.append("Client country: " + country);
  return buffer.toString();
 }

 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if ((obj instanceof Client) && (((Client) obj).getName() == this.name)) {
   return true;
  }
  return false;
 }

}
```

In hibernate mapping files i have this:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="test.domain">
 <class name="Client" table="clients" dynamic-update="true">
  <id name="id" column="clientId" type="integer">
   <generator class="increment" />
  </id>
  <property name="name" column="name" type="string" />
  <property name="company" column="company" type="string" />
  <property name="location" column="location" type="string" />
  <property name="city" column="city" type="string" />
  <property name="country" column="country" type="string" />

 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and

```
<hibernate-mapping package="test.domain">
 <class name="Project" table="project" dynamic-update="true">
  <id name="id" column="projectId" type="integer">
   <generator class="increment" />
  </id>
  <property name="name" column="name" type="string" />
  <property name="description" column="description" type="string" />
  <property name="startDate" column="start_date" type="string" />
  <property name="endDate" column="end_date" type="string" />
  <property name="manager" column="manager" type="string" />

  <!-- a client has many projects -->
  <many-to-one name="client" column="clientId"
   class="test.domain.Client" cascade="save-update" lazy="false" />

 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And i receive this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for description in class test.domain.Client
 at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.createGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:282)
 at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.getGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:275)
```

Way to wrapped out into this problem and now i don't even know if this is the correct way to declare the relations between the client and the project. Do you see a mistake in the code above? Thank you very much anyway.

Comment: that error is something really basic -- no getter for description on Client.  Thing is, in your mapping and code, description is on Project.  Do you have an extra hbm.xml somewhere?  Did you try a clean rebuild?

Answer (score 0):

i found out that the problem was my attention, this code worked fine, but there was an error in another hbm.xml, a duplicate name Clients instead of the required one.
I was looking in the wrong place, it was my mistake.
Thank you.